# Screenreader NVDA can´t read content that is createt by angularjs repeat-directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, screen-readers

```
<!-- <section ng-controller="problemDatabaseController">
<h4 >Aktuelle Probleme (aus Datenbank):</h4>
     <ul>
       <h1>{{problem.description}}</h1>
       <li class="problem" ng-repeat="problem in probleme">
         <p class="problemName">{{problem.description}}</p>
          Status: {{problem.created}}.
         <p class="problemBeschreibung">Problembeschreibung: {{problem.title}}</p>
     <ul>
       <li class="tag" ng-repeat="tag in problem.tags"><a href="index.html">{{tag.name}</a>    
       </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

If this is rendered, for instance the h1-tag is always unreadable because it is empty and all the other content too.
Is there anyway to make it readable for screenreaders?